# What is the correct way to declare this function prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi I am new to typescript & I have 2 component in my project, Input Dialog & Setting menu component.
I am using `inputDialog` inside the `settingmenu` component

my input dialog component is like this

```
interface InputDialogContentProps {
  inputLabel: string;
  inputType: string;
  onChange?: any;
}

export default function InputDialogContent(props: InputDialogContentProps) {
  const classes = inputDialogStyle();

  return (
    <DialogContent className={classes.dialogContentPlacement}>
      <TextField
        autoFocus
        className={classes.textFieldStyle}
        margin="dense"
        id="name"
        label={props.inputLabel}
        type={props.inputType}
        onChange={props.onChange}
        fullWidth
      />
    </DialogContent>
```

Please take note that I declare on change as `any` in this component.

here is my setting menu document.

```
<InputDialogContent
            inputLabel="Email Address"
            inputType="email"
            onChange={onInputChange}
          />

function onInputChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) {
    setEnableLoginButton(isValidEmail(e.target.value));
  }
```

As you can see i am using onChange to keep track of the changes inside the html text area.
So Rather than `any` What is the right way to declare this `Onchange` inside the inputDialog Component

Answer (score 1):

It would be:

```
interface InputDialogContentProps {
  inputLabel: string;
  inputType: string;
  onChange?: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void;
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

That's a function that accepts a single parameter of type `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>` and doesn't return anything. The general form is:

```typescript
(parameters) => returnType;
```

More in [the TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#function-types).

Comment: Isn't it possible to just do `onChange?: ReturnType<typeof React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>>;` ?

Comment: @Joel - I'm not following what you're trying to do there ([it doesn't work as shown](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgElqwBXGAEWBQBsIAcwDCEWkloAFHGADOcAN7k4cGpxgAZFACMk-AFxw5MKDSEVV6rgBUAnmCRGTZ6hfIB6D6vEiAFihuSAD8RgAUTojEMAB0-oFCSACiAG6SMAA8ABI2ALKaNkgAHjAAgkQoSfxIIOkAfACUcAC8dXApEMAAJpZwvgFBoVEwHFDU9o4ZMA5IEJhR6LHxQanp2XkFxWUVVTX1deQAvpSYHNQYwOJ91Gway4kRRsiLcQOJq7Tr+YUl5ai7tVojSUKlUcDQ4jkEGqMUEQgiDQox3IXSQaH4KCIcGq8CKRluXF4AmEYgk0lkcgoRRi-QSzGa1wJMHuSAoQA)), but the type in the answer is the simple, direct way to do this.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-forked-rke63?file=/src/index.tsx like this.

Comment: it's work.```const onInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
 //do something
 console.log(e.target.value);
};```

Comment: @Joel - That code doesn't run. But the gist of what you seem to be saying is `onChange?: ReturnType<typeof onInputChange>;` where `onInputChange` is a function declared elsewhere. The correct way to do that would be `onChange?: typeof onInputChange` (not using `ReturnType`; the `ReturnType` of the `onInputChange` in your code is `void`). **But**, that's putting the cart before the horse. You'd have to have a function to refer to, whereas when defining a component, you write a props interface and then *consumers* of the component write the function to pass in as a prop.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, didn't think changes would be applied when i didn't save. (opened a new tab and saw that it affected the example even tho i hadn't saved the temporary changes).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder But yeah, I was mostly curious if it was possible to do it any other way, but you're right, I was jumping the gun, my example just enforces an event that returns `void`.